# Flutter SIP call from background service

Tags: flutter, sip

I'm making a Flutter SIP call application using dart-sip-ua https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/dart-sip-ua.
I need to use PUSH messages to wake up the application and set the call.
I was able to wake up the application, but how to connect with the current call?

According to the documentation, when making a call, a Call object is created and it has an `answer()` method.
But when the Call object wakes up, we do not have, respectively, the `answer()` method either.

I tried to find a solution using `SIPUAHelper.findCall(callUUID)`, but without success: callUUID is generated when the call is initialized, and we do not know it in advance to pass it via PUSH.

That is, I show my CallScreen, but I don’t have a `Call` object...
Is there really only one option? Wait until the SIP connects itself? It could be 5, 10, 30 seconds...

Help me please. What is the approach to accomplish this task? I feel that my approach is not correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your problem could be to store the Call object in a persistent storage, such as a database or a file, whenever it is created. Then, when the application wakes up and receives the PUSH message, you can retrieve the Call object from the storage and pass it to the CallScreen. To do this, you can use a database library like "sqflite" or a file library like "path_provider" to store and retrieve the Call object as a serialized object.

Another option could be to use the "callUUID" of the Call object as a key to store and retrieve it from the storage. You can pass the "callUUID" via PUSH message, and use it to retrieve the Call object from the storage. However, you need to make sure that the "callUUID" is unique and persistent across sessions, so you may need to use a combination of the SIP call ID and the local session ID.

A third option could be to use a global state manager like "Provider" or "Redux" to store the Call object and share it across the application. This way, you can access the Call object from any widget, even if it is not passed directly as an argument. However, you need to be careful with the performance and complexity of using a global state manager, especially if you have a large and complex application.

I hope these suggestions can help you solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
It's not quite right.
We never have the Call object... That was the question. Probably, I need to think about how to always connect to the SIP. Because if there is a connection, the call works even without a PUSH message.
Thank you! I'll think about how to solve the problem :)

Comment: @Aidar : I am facing same issue in android app using flutter_background_service where i am able to run the call after kill state but not able to get any data after back in application.
if you find any solution please reply
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KDOSHI, I didn't quite understand your problem.
So far I have solved the problem like this: in the background process, when a push comes in, I create a second connection to the SIP. He registers and almost immediately receives a new call. Works in about 2-4 seconds. Then I close the second connection. And so in a circle.
Not the best solution, but anyway :)